# clarification: Database, DBMS, SOA, REST

Tags: sql, rest, soa, web-frameworks, nosql

Hi everyone I’m new to server-side technologies so maybe this is a bit of a dumb question but after reading dozens of articles and viewing dozens of videos I’m still very confused. This has to do with arquitecture principles of modern apps.

**Relational model:**
I know that a few years ago the model was to have a database (mostly relational) and a DBMS that enabled the connection between an app and the database.

Question 1: Since we are talking about a relational model some examples of DBMS’s are MySQL or PostgreSQL? 
Question 2: What is the process of information exchange? The client-side uses a language like PHP to make a request to the server and then the DBMS transforms the request into SQL and accesses the database? Is the conversion of the PHP into SQL part of DBMS function or another server-side software is needed? 
(If someone could provide me summary detailed explanation I would be very thankful)

**Non-Relational Models:**

Question 2: Nowadays with the rise of NoSQL models does the same concept of DBMS apply? Since these systems allow other querying language other than SQL there should be some piece of software that has this function?

**Service Oriented Arquitecture:**
Almost every app uses this type of arquitecture. I understand the concept of avoid the creation of too tight software relation between client and server side allowing for multiple use across several platforms. What I don’t understand is what parts constitute a system that is build this way.

Question 3: Does the DBMS provides the API’s that constitute the web services made available?

**Web Frameworks:**
Last but not least, where do frameworks like Django or Ruby on Rails land on?

Question 4: These are supposed to provide tools to develop everything between the front-end and the database of a SOA system right?

Question 5: I’ve seen a lot of buzz about REST arquitecture. Can you explain me of the querying process happens and what are the software entities involved.

Thank you in advance for any explanation that helps me understating these questions. Please provide some links or any diagrams that you find useful.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Object Relational Mapping(ORM) is a whole class of tools on how to go from data in a database to objects in code that has more than a few ways to do things: Hibernate, Linq2Sql, Entity Framework, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping would be the Wikipedia link to start you down this yellow brick road.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tackle your questions individually:

> Question 1: Since we are talking about a relational model some examples of DBMS’s are MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Correct. The Database Management System is the suite of software that lets you interact with a particular database technology. The examples you give are correct.

> Question 2: What is the process of information exchange? The client-side uses a language like PHP to make a request to the server and then the DBMS transforms the request into SQL and accesses the database? Is the conversion of the PHP into SQL part of DBMS function or another server-side software is needed?

There are many different avenues for this. Typically the API for accessing a database is done via ODBC (Open Database Connectivity). ODBC drivers are available for most (if not all) Relational DB vendors and are all very similar.

A language like PHP could connect to the database via an ODBC connection library (eg http://php.net/manual/en/intro.uodbc.php) which would allow you to send CRUD operations to the DBMS to be executed on the database.

Since most DBMS's use a subset or superset of a SQL standard for querying the database you can either pass this code directly via ODBC or you may use another level of abstraction. A common method is called an ORM (Object Relational Mapper). ORMs (eg SQLAlcmehy for Python: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) provides an abstraction layer so you're not reliant on writing SQL but instead write queries and database commands in a format more common of your language of choice.

> Question 2: Nowadays with the rise of NoSQL models does the same concept of DBMS apply? Since these systems allow other querying language other than SQL there should be some piece of software that has this function?

Same general concept (in that there is a DB Driver that exposes an API that languages can hook into) but there are generally more and differing ways of interacting with DB's now since they have many differing structures. Most NoSQL DBs still have ODBC connectors (eg MongoDB and Hadoop) so the general programming practices still apply whilst connecting with them, but the things you expect the database to do (and their natural query languages) will differ.

This continues to be an evolving space as these technologies evolve.

> Question 3: Does the DBMS provides the API’s that constitute the web services made available?

Not sure I'm understanding this question. ODBC and webservices are different. Often webservices sit on top of ODBC if you want to query a database via a web API, but it's one layer of abstraction more than connecting to the DB directly via ODBC.

> Last but not least, where do frameworks like Django or Ruby on Rails land on?

Web Frameworks are a way of quickening the development of web applications by trying to stop some of the "reinvent the wheel" things that you commonly do with every web application. They give you the basics, and have a lot of extensions that allow you to implement other common elements of web apps (like a subscription/login system, session management, admin system etc).

> These are supposed to provide tools to develop everything between the front-end and the database of a SOA system right?

Both Django and RoR aim to be end-to-end frameworks. They include all the common elements you'll need including an Object Relational Mapper. They don't prescribe which DBMS you have to use, their ORMs can interface with many so that choice is still up to you.

Yes, they are aimed to cover everything from the front end to the DB, including the interaction with and initialization of the structure of the database.

> Question 5: I’ve seen a lot of buzz about REST arquitecture. Can you explain me of the querying process happens and what are the software entities involved.

REST stands for Representational State Transfer (quick Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). In a nutshell the creation of a "RESTful" (REST compliant) web API would mean that you have  GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods to accomplish all your services. REST aligns closely with the HTTP protocol which is why it's been very appropriate for the ever growing concept of Web Apps, it's helped transform the thinking from a Web Page (or set of web pages) into Web Apps.

It's hard to sum up better than the Wikipedia article does, I'd suggest you dive into it.

Hope that's cleared up a few of the questions!

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer. It was really clear. Just wanna ask you one more question. I included a diagram in my question that shows more or less what i understood, can you point me if i'm in the right path?

Comment: Yes, that diagram covers it well in a nutshell. Definitely on the right path.